# JUnit deferred assertion message creation

Tags: java, junit

I'm using JUnit assertion message to output some debugging information:

```
assertEquals(debugString, a, b);
```

Creation of this string is expensive, and I want to create it only if the assertion failed. How can I do this?

Comment: JUnit's standard Assert does not support lazy creation of error message. Did you have a look at Hamcrest. It has nice error messages that are only created if the test fails AFAIK.

Comment: @StefanBirkner I didn't. Looks nice. Make an answer, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but you can simulate all the asserts yourself using `if`s and `fail`. E.g., instead of:

```
assertEquals(debugString, a, b);
```

Your test could have:

```
if (!a.equals(b)) {
    fail (debugString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/), which creates messages only on failure AFAIK.

```
String x ="x";
String y="y";
assertThat(x, is(equalTo(y));
```

In case of a failure it generates

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "y"
     but: was "x"
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, once JUnit 5 is available you'll be able to create messages with a function parameter, which only is evaluated when an assertion fails.  It's form could be something like this:

```
 assertTrue(() -> expensiveMessage(), testResult == expectedResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the AssertionError, and then rethrow it with your message.  Some sample code I just wrote was over a 100 times faster when the message creation was moved out of the loop:

```
@Test
public void shouldHaveCorrectParameters() {
  for(int r = 1; r <= 50; r++) {
    for(int mce = 1; mce <= 64; mce++) {
      Encoder encoder = new Encoder(r, mce);

      for(int l = 1; l <= 16384; l++) {
        EncodeParameters params = encoder.determineParameters(l);
        double effectiveRedundancy = (params.n - params.k) * 100 / (double)params.k;

        try {
          assertTrue(params.n - params.k >= mce);
          assertTrue(params.n - params.k <= mce * 2);
          assertTrue(effectiveRedundancy >= r);
        }
        catch(AssertionError e) {
          String msg = "redundancy=" + r + "%; minimumCorrectableErrors=" + mce + "; fileLength=" + l + "; k=" + params.k + "; n=" + params.n + String.format("; effectiveRedundancy=%.3f%%", effectiveRedundancy);

          throw new AssertionError(msg, e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```